# Does Detective Somerset stay as a detective?

Tags: plot-explanation, se7en

In the movie Se7en, a plot line is around whether detective Somerset is going to retire.

1. During the initial wife-shoots-husband scene, an unnamed detective berates Somerset by saying: we will be so happy to be rid of you.
2. Captain of the precinct, while handing over a bottle of plastics to Somerset, tries to convince him to stay with the force.
3. After detective Mills shoots John Doe, the Captain asks Somerset again, and this time he replies, I will be around, around. Followed by a narration of "the world is a nice place and worth fighting for, I believe the second part."

I have this feeling Somerset decides to stay with the police force after all that happens.

Is there any way to clarify this?

Comment: “I will be around” could also be translated “I’m still retiring but I’ll help out when needed.” I know several friends and family who retired/resigned from their jobs but stayed as outside consultants or as part time fillers afterward, at least until things had fully transitioned over.

Comment: We have no way of knowing because the story ends and we are not told what happens after that. It's pure speculation and contributes nothing to the appreciation of the movie in my opinion. (Did Mills die in prison? does he get parole for good behavior?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It's unclear in the movie but possibly, yes.

Certainly, it *seems* as though Somerset will continue as a police officer but we are given no indication other than his quoting Hemingway

> > "The world is a fine place and worth fighting for."
>
> I agree with the second part

which would imply that he will continue to fight for it.

The [**SCRIPT**](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/seven_production.html) however gives us a little more insight.

We know that Somerset was planning on moving out of the city when he retires and fixing up a property...indicated by a piece of wallpaper he carries

The final section of the script has him apparently abandoning the idea to return to action.

> ```
> A father passes by, holding his young son's hand.  Somerset turns
>  to watch them pass.  The father reaches to pick the son up and
>  carry him in his arms.  The boy laughs and holds tight.
>
> The father hugs his son to him, kisses him on the cheek.  The boy
>  returns the kiss with great affection.
>
> Somerset watches them disappear in the mass of humanity.  He
>  looks back at the two papers in his hands.  He lets out a sigh.
>
>                              SOMERSET
>                       (to himself)
>               Oh... man...
>
> He sighs again, drained.
>
> He puts the pale paper rose inside the note from Mills.  He folds
>  them together.
>
> He tears them both up, into little pieces.
>
>            EXT.  PRECINCT HOUSE -- DAY
>
> Cars roll by in the street.  Cops come and go.
>
> Somerset walks up the stairs, into the precinct house.  The doors
>  shut behind him.
> ```